# Error: illegal character '#'

Tags: logicblox

I tried running the logic file from Doop test set in Logic Blox 3.10. I run the `analysis.js` file in `1-call-site-sensitive` folder 
using following commands in sequence:

```
lb create testworkspace
lb exec testworkspace --file analysis.logic
```

It prompts me the following errors:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/doop/logic/1-call-site-sensitive$ lb exec testworkspace --file analysis.logic
Error: block __block0: line 8: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #include "macros.logic"
    ^

block __block0: line 8: error: unexpected token 'macros.logic' (code: UNEXPECTED_TOKEN)
    #include "macros.logic"
                          ^

block __block0: line 9: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #include "../context-sensitive.logic"
    ^

block __block0: line 10: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #include "../library.logic"
    ^

block __block0: line 47: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #ifdef PADDLE_COMPAT
    ^

block __block0: line 47: error: unexpected token 'PADDLE_COMPAT' (code: UNEXPECTED_TOKEN)
    #ifdef PADDLE_COMPAT
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

block __block0: line 48: error: unexpected token '.' (code: UNEXPECTED_TOKEN)
      MethodInvocationValue(?startupInvocation, "<<no-context>>").
                                                                 ^

block __block0: line 49: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #else
    ^

block __block0: line 51: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #endif
    ^

block __block0: line 62: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #ifdef PADDLE_COMPAT
    ^

block __block0: line 64: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #else
    ^

block __block0: line 66: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #endif
    ^

block __block0: line 73: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #ifdef PADDLE_COMPAT
    ^

block __block0: line 75: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #else
    ^

block __block0: line 77: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #endif
    ^

block __block0: line 85: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #ifdef PADDLE_COMPAT
    ^

block __block0: line 87: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #else
    ^

block __block0: line 89: error: illegal character '#' (code: ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)
    #endif

    ^

18 ERRORS (BloxCompiler version 73677_d4ce8757cf9e9f444fdfe6fd6e4f43064577d1e8)
```

Am I running it correctly? I have attached all the files I have run with LogicBlox in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qnhh52le1fr9jl/logic.7z?dl=0):

Answer (score -1):

Doop currently supports only version 3.X (preferably 3.9 or 3.10) of the LogicBlox engine. Furthermore, doop is a whole framework. It's not just a logic file. In order to run doop, you have to invoke the wrapping script or gradlew directly.

I suggest you check this tutorial from PLDI'15. http://plast-lab.github.io/doop-pldi15-tutorial/